# Linux + LDAP/ActiveDirectory: Can't create a private group for the user like "username:username"

Tags: linux, authentication, pam, ldap, active-directory

My apologies first for not phrasing this question very well, because it's difficult to Google. (Try finding a Google answer with the terms "self user group" in it.)

Normally, with PAM in Linux, when you create a user "foo" it the `useradd` command will create a group called `foo` as well and the user will be the sole member of that group.

However, with ActiveDirectory, once you create a user account named "foo", you cannot also create a security group called "foo".

This is creating a problem for our OpenLDAP -> AD conversion, because we used to have user groups in LDAP that mirrored their accounts. I guess I'm not apposed to doing away with this practice, but that means we have a *ton* of filesystem cleanup to do.

## EDIT

If it wasn't clear, the question is: how do you get a user to be the sole member of their own group when your authorization/authentication backend is LDAP backed by ActiveDirectory? If you don't understand these concepts, then you have no business downvoting the question, because it *very* much is Unix related and is indeed on-topic for StackExchange Unix.

Comment: What is the question you're asking? It's not entirely clear what the question is.

Comment: @John It's a hard question to phrase.  As someone who just faced this a few years ago I know exactly what he's up against but I can't really describe it very well either.

Comment: I think this is off-topic. I'm not flagging it as such because there isn't an option for another stackexchange where this should be addressed. I think it belongs to superuser.  I think the answer is simply: don't try to map AD "security groups" to unix groups. Alternatively, there might be a mapping mechanism to go between AD group names and unix group names.

Comment: @Otheus If anywhere it should be moved to ServerFault but given that it's dealing primarily with U/L groups and permissions I think this is a fine place for it.

Comment: I don't feel strongly about it, but there is really nothing unix-specific here. The question, abstractly put, is: how do you set up groups in AD so that they can be migrated from system X? The _answer_ might be specific to a UNIX solution, but the quesiton isn't.

Comment: @exabrial: the google phrase you're looking for in the first paragraph is "user private group".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We went though this exact same thing a few years ago when we did an OpenLDAP->AD migration.  We never did find a solution but we also discovered that this is only the first of several ways that groups get funky in AD.  We opted to do the filesystem cleanup because once you make the transition all of your uid's and gid's are going to change which means you'll have to redo all of your Unix permissions anyway.

Feel free to contact me directly if you want more help/advice on the migration.

Comment: The UID values don't have to change - you can manually set the UID values in AD once you've installed the SFU extensions.

Comment: We found that the SFU extensions caused more problems than they solved.  It was easier, in our experience, to just deal with the UID's changing.

Comment: Doesn't the LDAP client libraries offer some nifty, complex mapping lookup functions? Seems to me you could have unix groups `joe`, `sam`, `mary` as `UX_joe`, `UX_sam`, `UX_mary` and both these are in what is essentially the LDAP version of a _join table_. The LDAP client libs lookup the groups in that join table, not the regular AD group field.

Comment: I'm going to bet that the "best" solution (read: least bad) available is to use RH's integration bits available in RHEL 7 IdM, or the equivalent bits for whatever distribution you're using. My experience with IdM was that it took out a *lot* of the Windows funkiness from the equation, and made things almost trivially easy.

Comment: @DavidKing Thank you very much for taking the time to speak intelligibly and provide clear advice to the problem via your personal experience. We'll likely follow in your footsteps and do the filesystem migration.